# $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); only returns even rows

Tags: php, mysql

We have this code:

```
$rowArray;
$rowID = 1;
$query = "SELECT idCentros FROM centros";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
        $rowArray[$rowID] = $row['idCentros'];   
        $rowID = $rowID +1;
    }
```

$numrows returns 4 (the rows we have in that table)...but for an unkown reason the loop starts retrieving the 2º row next it retrieves the 4º row and then it ends the loop ($row =false). As we understand this is generic code and the table definition is like this:

```
column idcentros int(11)      pk notnull autoincremental
column nombre    mediumtext
```

What could be happening? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I once had this issue, never did figure out what was wrong, but using "mysql_fetch_assoc" instead of "mysql_fetch_array" worked for me.

Comment: I executed the same code in the project sample from which i based and it does it ok....the databases are in the same mysql instance, both projects executed from same enviroment...what the heck? :S

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT idCentros FROM centros";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$rowArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   array_push($rowArray,$row);
}
```

Comment: With your code it now starts on the 3rd row and then it exits the loop (becouse there isnt a 5th row to retrieve...) It always skips one row after fetching and in this case starts in the 3rd row :S

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the above code shouldn't work, but ... here's how I would do it:

```
$rowArray = array();
$query = "SELECT idCentros FROM centros";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $rowArray[] = $row[0];
}
```

... I believe you have `$rowID` set to `1` just for visualisation later, but it's pointless - you should use HTML lists or some `$counter++` variable for the output.